# How to stay connected in website using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to connect to a website with Proxy and stay connected there, for let's say 10 seconds.

My script:

```
import requests
url = 'http://WEBSITE.com/'

proxies ={'http': 'http://IP:PORT'}

s = requests.Session();
s.proxies.update(proxies)
s.get(url);
```

As much as I learnt, I came up with this script which connects to the website but I think it does not stay connected, what should I do so this script connects to the website with proxy and stays connected?

Comment: you can try with Prepared Requests     https://2.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/

Comment: Try connecting with these headers: `connection: keep-alive` and `keep-alive: timeout=10`

Comment: @will_f how do i add these headers?

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: @will_f please Check my comment on RHP's comment , i wanted to ask same question to you

Comment: If admin has read access to server logs (which should be true), they will see timestamps for each GET request and be able to tell when you've made such requests.

Comment: Its understood , could you explain to me what is GET meaning exactly? , what are we getting ? i find so many answers to that question but i couldnt really set it on my mind

Comment: @will_f all so i am sorry that i mentioned Google analytics as admin :D , what i tried to explain was that I want to connect to a Website , stay till google analytics accepts as Online user and Shows on Admin Panel , and disconnect

Comment: The server is running on a computer, and you can _think of it_ as a program that read/writes/executes things in the computer's file system.  In the snippet you developed, you are asking the server to get and return to you the resource specified by "/".  You can also request the server to change something in the file system, which encompasses requests like PATCH and DELETE, or even add something to the file system with POST.  In my answer the hyperlinks to Mozilla will be helpful to learn more, and also read up on IETF's RFCs on HTTP

Comment: I think that you only have to check if the server's response status is 200, which means the server acknowledged your request

Comment: response = s.get(url)
if(response.status_code == 200)
   Print("Executed") 
 like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Session` object doesn't necessarily keep the connection alive.  To that end this might work:

```py
import requests


url = 'http://WEBSITE.com/'
proxies = {'http': 'http://IP:PORT'}
headers = {
    "connection" : "keep-alive",
    "keep-alive" : "timeout=10, max=1000"
}


s = requests.Session();
s.proxies.update(proxies)
s.get(url, headers=headers);
```

See [connection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection), and [keep-alive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive) headers :)

edit: after reviewing the `requests` documentation, I learned that the `Session` object can also be used to store headers.  Here is a slightly better answer:

```py
import requests


url = 'http://WEBSITE.com/'
proxies = {'http': 'http://IP:PORT'}
headers = {
    "connection" : "keep-alive",
    "keep-alive" : "timeout=10, max=1000"
}


s = requests.Session()
s.proxies.update(proxies)
s.headers.update(headers)
s.get(url)
```

Comment: The thing is that this program runs in about 3 seconds and finished right ? even tho we set keep-alive.
But i want to stay connected atleast 20 minutes lets say. Do I have to set countdown and keep calling s.get?

Comment: Ya, you’ll have to keep calling `s.get`. Use `time.sleep` to space the GETs out so the server doesn’t “get mad” at you

Comment: Alternatively, it might be worthwhile to research if the connection should be upgraded to the websocket protocol? I’m not familiar with google analytics, so I’m not sure myself

Comment: will sorry for asking too many questions but , if i loop this s.proxies.update(proxies[]) and s.get(url) code for lets say 50 times. would it send 50 different connections to website?

Comment: Its because i tought that site might be writing to logs as like 1 entry from same ip from last 24 hours , i want to achieve like 100 entries in small amount of time

Comment: If you define the connection as the underlying tcp socket, there shouldn’t be 50 of these, however there generally will be at least 50 forked reads or writes. That’s what the keep-alive header is supposed to do, ie make sure one communication process is occurring on one underlying socket.

Comment: will my networking knowledge is not that great , so keep alive sets communication once and every other connection follows his connection? So if i wanted to achieve what i told you i need to keep-alive false ? to renew connection everytime ?